# Akamai HDCore + live stream = occasional blips of black

Tags: actionscript-3, buffer, flashplayer-10

I noticed I'd only getting the "blips of black" (maybe 300ms of all black) whenever the stream quality changes (due to the DSS throttle).

I thought maybe there is not enough buffer, but the stream change takes about 7s (according to the HDCore debug messages) and the bufferTime, according to the associated netStream, is set to 10 seconds by default.

Perhaps there's a better way to set up the buffer in HDCore? This worked fine with OSMF, but OSMF doesn't support HTTP DSS.

Using: **Flash Player 10.2** and **Akamai HDCore 2.1.20**

Embed Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*var str = '?';
    for(var b in flashVars) str += b + '=' + flashVars[b] + '&';
    alert(str);*/
var params = {
        allowFullScreen:"true",
        wmode:"window",
        bgcolor:"#000000"
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF(WEBCAST_SWF_URL, "flashContent", "512", "288", "10.2.0", "/flash/expressinstall.swf?", null, params);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that running locally and hitting the swf both worked find.

So I changed the wrapper in the HTML and that fixed the "blip". I switched from swfobject to the native non-swfobject wrapper and everything worked (AC_OETags.js).

Happy streaming.

Comment: try swfobject with wmode = window

Comment: post your embedding method then

Comment: I added the embed method (swfobject). Also, it seems that the blip only shows when DSS selects the highest quality stream, yet the blip never shows when I run locally. I tried modifying the buffer, both bigger and smaller, but saw no change. I'm at a loss :(

Comment: Hi Jackson, I'm hitting an almost identical issue playing videos back in flash - wasn't totally clear based on your answer did your change fix the issue or were you still getting that behavior?

Comment: I noticed it only happened when it did DSS to stream 6 (the highest quality stream). So I chalked it up to be something with only that particular stream. Either way, the client stopped mentioning it so maybe it was on the encoding side? GL.